# $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{e} (\log x)^n dx $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{3} (\log x)^n dx $

Tags: real-analysis

I want to calculate this limit.Can I prove the uniformly convergence of the succession so i can exchange limit and integral?

Comment: The second limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: And there is no uniform convergence here.

Comment: in the first case I found $\int_{0}^{1} u^n e^u du$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed small $\varepsilon>0$,
$$ 0\le \log x\le\log(e-\varepsilon)<1, x\in[1,e-\varepsilon]$$
and hence
$$ \int_{1}^{e} (\log x)^n dx=\int_{1}^{e-\varepsilon} (\log x)^n dx +\int_{e-\varepsilon}^{e} (\log x)^n dx \le(\log(e-\varepsilon))^n(e-1)+\varepsilon. $$
Letting $n\to\infty$ gives
$$ 0\le\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\int_{1}^{e} (\log x)^n dx\le\varepsilon$$
and thus one has
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{e} (\log x)^n dx=0.$$
One can use the same to show
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{1}^{3} (\log x)^n dx=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Both integrals can be tackled through the substitution $x=e^{z}$, without switching $\lim$ and $\int$.

$$0\leq  \int_{1}^{e}\left(\log x\right)^n\,dx  = \int_{0}^{1} z^n e^{z}\,dz \leq e\int_{0}^{1}z^n\,dz = \frac{e}{n+1}\to 0, $$
$$\int_{1}^{3}\left(\log x\right)^n\,dx \geq \int_{1}^{\log 3}z^n e^{z}\,dz \geq e\frac{\left(\log 3\right)^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\to +\infty.$$